# EOF doesnt work when working with fgets

Tags: c, file

I've tried to read whole file with `fgets`, and when I use it in while loop, it never ends.
When I use `fscanf` everything works fine.

```
while((fscanf(f,"%s",ime)) != EOF)
   {
       fputs(ime,p);
       fputc('\n',p);
   }
```

But this doesn't work, how to fix it? I get infinite loop

```
while((fgets(ime,100,f)) != EOF)
    {
        fputs(ime,p);
        fputc('\n',p);
    }
```

What should I put instead `!= EOF` so loop ends when it is end of text in file?

Comment: note that with fscanf you should be using `== 1` rather than `!= EOF` anyway. It doesnt really matter for `%s`, but does for other specifiers

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Is it really this hard to read the [documentation](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_fgets.htm)?

> ```
> char *fgets(char *str, int n, FILE *stream)
> ```
>
> On success, the function returns the same str parameter. If the End-of-File is encountered and no characters have been read, the contents of str remain unchanged and a null pointer is returned.
>   If an error occurs, a null pointer is returned.

```
while((fgets(ime,100,f)) != NULL)
```

Answer (score 3):

Change to

```
while((fgets(ime,100,f)) != NULL)
```

---

According to man page

> `char *fgets(char *s, int size, FILE *stream);`
>
> fgets() return s on success, and NULL on error or when end
>          of file occurs while no characters have been read.

Comment: Works perfect ! Thanks :)